# Scrape yahoo finance stock prices to google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

So I can get the xpath working for "mainstream" stocks like CVNA with this line:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CVNA?p=CVNA";"//*[@id='quote-header-info']");;3); "\d+.\d+|\d+")+0
```

But when trying to point to a specific exchange like Oslo exchange I get an error.
Would like to scrape stock prices from NEL.OL

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you can find the answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=importxml+Resource+at+url+not+found.)

Answer (score 0):

As the page is built in javascript on the client side and not on the server side, you will not be able to retrieve the data by the importxml / importhtml functions. However, the page contains a json which you can retrieve and analyze to retrieve the information you need.

```
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

for instance, for marketprice, you can retrieve the informations by

```
function marketPrice(code) {
  var url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+code
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  var regularMarketPrice = data.context.dispatcher.stores.StreamDataStore.quoteData[code].regularMarketPrice.raw
  return regularMarketPrice
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sTA71PhpxI_QdGKXVAtb0Rc3cmvPLgzvXKXXTmiec7k/copy - column G